# Reloading Python modules with R reticulate package

Tags: r, reticulate

I would like to know if there is a way to reload modules imported into R via the `reticulate` package, similar to the `autoreload` extension for IPython. For example, suppose I am developing my own module locally, I might import it via

```
library(reticulate)
import_from_path("mypackage", "/path/to/package")
```

However, if I make code changes to `mypackage` the only way I can think to reflect them is to restart R. This is consistent with normal Python behavior where modules cannot be reloaded. One workaround would be to source a file from the package in which I am making changes, i.e.

```
source_python("/path/to/package/file.py")
```

However, if `file.py` is importing other files in the local package that are being changed than changes to those files will not be reflected.

Comment: If you use devtools you can use `load_all()` to load your package in and reload when changes are made.

Comment: My understanding is that `load_all` is just for R packages, whereas here I am importing a Python package into R.

Comment: I think, this would be really nice feature!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible by calling Python commands to reload:

For Python 2.7

```
> builtins <- import_builtins()
> builtins$reload(your_module)
```

For Python 3

```
> importlib <- import("importlib")
> importlib$reload(your_module)
```